# Get accesstoken from Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET without Login into the Web Server

Tags: azure-ad-msal

i am building a saas website(aspnetcore webapi 2.1+angular js) which allow user to connect thier email account(Gmail,outlook mail..),so they can receive and send email without switching out.  i have completed the  gmail part smoothly, but when i come to  outlook mail, i stucked on the authentication part.  what i wan't (and i have already done on Gmail intergration) are :

1. direct user to the Login page with necessary parameters(tenantid,clientid..)(https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.....)
2. when user is logined in, store the tokens in database, and manage them(get new refreshtoken and accesstoken after expired automatically).

   i have read a lot articles on msdn,github,stackoverflow, and found the nearest solution is this one:
   https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-tutorial, but it logins the ms user to the my website. i just wan't to popup/redirect the user to  microsoft  login page, and  get the user's accesstoken to get/send thire emails through Microsoft Graphy Api, not login as a microsoft account.  i can't found  similar code to Google API  in MSAL

   ````
   credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                       GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                       scopes,
                       tokenId,
                       CancellationToken.None,
                       //  new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                       (IDataStore)userApiTokenRepository       //<------------token management
                       , new LocalServerCodeReceiver(
                                   @"<html>
                                   <head>
                                   <script>
                                   window.onload(function(){window.setTimeout(3000,function(){window.close();}});
                                   </script>
                                   </head><body>Successfully linked with gmail!</body></html>")
                       ).Result;```
   ````

the code above will direct to google login page(even it is called via http post from js client), and store them in my customer repository. do i miss something in the MSAL, or i must implent the 0auth flow manually?

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token for MS Graph the user has to sign-in first so you can send their credentials to acquire the token. You cannot bypass the 1st sign-in page.

MSAL can do this for you, by interception the openIdConnect event `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` and then calling `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` with the code received. I would recommend you to take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache), set a breakpoint on `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` and analyze the flow that is happening there.

About implementing the flow manually, it will be a hard task to deal with the token expiration and the security points. I would highly recommend to use MSAL.